# Two authors in a reference: converting “and” to comma

Tags: bibtex, citing

As I said in the title I have a problem with bibliography and citations: I use the `unsrt` BibTeX style. I know that in order to separate different authors in the `authors` field in a .bib file I have to use `and` instead of the comma. That works perfectly when there are more than two authors in my citation, but when there are only two authors I noticed that there are no commas displayed in the output.

e.g.

```
  \documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
  ...

  \bibliographystyle{unsrt}
  \bibliograpy{bibfilename}
```

Here is two entries for the bibfilename.bib, respectively with three and two authors:

```
  \begin{thebibliography}

  @article{article1,
  title = {Title1},
  volume = {123},
  number = {11},
  journal = {Journal},
  author = {Power, J. and Rower, C. and Atkins, D.},
  year = {2012},
  pages = {5780--5817}
  },
```

that correctly produce

> J. Power, C. Rower, D. Atkins ...

and then

```
  @article{article2,
  title = {Title2},
  volume = {123},
  number = {3},
  urldate = {2013-10-26},
  journal = {Journal 2},
  author = {Power, J. and Rower, C.},
  year = {1995},
  pages = {211--220},
  },
```

that produce

> J. Power C. Rower

without the separating comma. How can I fix this problem? Thank you in advance.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Most important: can you show the actual `author` field? It should be `author={Power, J. and Rower, C. and Atkins, D.}` (recommended) or `author={J. Power and C. Rower and D. Atkins}`; for two authors it should be `author={Power, J. and Rower, C.}` or `author={J. Power and C. Rower}`